# Blender’s scale for STL export for 3D Print

Tags: transforms, 3d-printing

just trying to export a model out correctly for 3d Printing.

But when I send it to the printing company they say the scale is out by a factor of 1000000.

As a simple example, here’s the settings I have, ie settings are in mm, everything has had transforms applied, Blender’s Unit Scale is a 1.0, but when imported say into Cura it auto scales to 1000000% , am I missing something?
[image]

Comment: This may help with the setup.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-Vq2O-hvfo  I used it for my 3D printing setup and it works.  I use Prusaslicer which is based on Cura.